# I downloaded pyaudio successfully,but i still couldn't have this error.Why?

Tags: python, pyaudio

```
def get_audio():
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    audio = r.listen(source)
    said = ""

    try:
        said = r.recognize_google(audio)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception:", str(e))

return said.lower()
```

And then : AttributeError Could not find PyAudio; check installation
My python version is :Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
And i downloaded "PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl"
Why?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In Terminal type

```
pip install pipwin
```

Then

```
pipwin install pyaudio
```